# Is there a mode of python that traces each line executed, similar to 'bash -x'?

Tags: python, debugging

I am running a python script in crontab that works fine from the command line but appears to not be running at all when it runs in cron. If this was a bash script, I would add 'bash -x' to the crontab and pipe STOUT and STDERR to a log file. Is there a similar mode of python that will capture the execution of each individual line of code within a script?

Comment: Did you already try logging stderr to a file, by the way? Unless your script is doing some really awful things (ie. `try: ...` `except: pass`), failures generally shouldn't be silent.

Comment: I did, but this is something that I would run very regularly with any python script, so I wanted something other than just logging print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The trace module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) does this.

```
python -m trace --trace yourscript.py
```